# Solving a limit without using L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

First time posting here. I would like to get some help with this limit. I'm expected to solve it without using L'Hopital's rule, as I haven't been taught said rule, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

$$\lim_{x\to3} \frac{(\sin(x-3))}{(x^2-9)}$$

Could someone nudge me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Hint: $\sin(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Remember $\frac{\sin x}{x}, x\to 0$.

Comment: Try factorizing the denominator and using $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have
$$
\frac{\sin (x-3)}{x^2-9}=\frac{1}{x+3}\cdot\frac{\sin (x-3)}{x-3}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{1}{x+3}=\frac{1}{6},
$$
while
$$
\lim_{x\to 3}\frac{\sin (x-3)}{x-3}
=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=\cdots
$$

Answer (score 3):

You can also use substitution $x-3=a \ ,\ a\to0 $
$$\lim_{x\to3} \frac{(\sin(x-3))}{(x^2-9)}\\x=a+3\\\lim_{a\to 0 }\frac {\sin a}{(a+3)^2-9}=\\\lim_{a\to 0 }\frac {\sin a}{a^2+6a+9-9}=\\\lim_{a\to 0 }\frac {\sin a}{a(a+6)}=?\\$$